# Mac OS Yosemite made TeXShop previews unreadably blurred

Tags: fonts, mac, texshop

I recently upgraded to OS X 10.10 Yosemite. To my great disappointment, TeXShop (3.43) built-in previews are blurred:[image]

I usually work on several pages documents and this kind of blur is very eye-tiring to me.

I tried (temporarily) switching to sans-serif fonts, but it doesn't get any better (nor does it by zooming under 200%). I also tried various combinations of font rendering options for Mac OS, again with no result at all.

Any suggestion (including other previewers which reportedly do not have this problem) is very welcome.

EDIT: Thanks everyone for reporting and pointing out possible solutions. As far as I understand the problem, it seems to be a combination of both Yosemite fonts rendering and TeXShop fonts processing. In my own case serif fonts are blurred everywhere, though the same fonts appear as more or less readable depending on the application (TeXShop pdf preview rendering is by far the worst). I summarize possible solutions, which I suggest to try in order:

- Change TeX previewer/editor [I tried many in the last days, the best of which seems to be TeXWorks, though all of them are far from satisfying to me, at least for zoom lesser than 180-190%]
- Turn off (uncheck) "Use LCD font smoothing when available" under 'System Preferences > General' [didn't work for most of users in the comments, yet slightly improved sans-serif fonts rendering in my TeXShop shell]
- Change anti aliasing (font smoothing) options via command line in terminal (detailed instructions may be found here http://mac.software.com/tweaks/change-font-smoothing) [slightly improved general rendering of sans-serif fonts in my case]
- As a last option, changing fonts might help a bit, especially for sans-serif ones

Comment: I've also updated to MacOSX "Yosemite", and when I create a test document using TeXshop 3.43, I get normal, i.e, non-fuzzy output. Can you tell us a bit more about your version of MacTeX? If would be helpful if you posted a specific test document that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

Comment: @Mico: I have reinstalled MacTex 2014 today (hoping it would solve the problem) (http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html). As for the test document, I'm having this blur issue on every file I've opened and they appear blurred even if I open them with Preview, so it seems to be a problem of the OS rather than of the editor. I tried to compile a new very basic document `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
AAAA vhjkhv
\end{document}` but the result is the same.

Comment: Does the same problem behavior occur if you use a different front-end program -- say, TeXworks -- to compile the MWE?

Comment: I just tried TeXworks and it worked quite fine: it is not as smooth as it was with TeXShop, but it's way better than with the actual TeXShop. Thank you for the suggestion! For the moment I will stick with TeXworks, but I'd like to find a solution for TeXShop too...

Comment: I have the same issue. But for me, the output looks fine in Preview and Adobe Reader. I tried the ghostscript installation, to no avail.

Comment: Ditto. I have made a few upgrades over the last couple of days: Xcode, ghostscript etc. I tried removing all copies of gs on my system (there seemed to be some legacy ones) and reinstalling gs 9.15, but no improvement. I'm wondering if there's some interference somewhere between something previously installed and the current versions. Of course I have no idea how to figure out what is actually happening :(

Comment: I have the same issue, which only appeared after installing Yosemite. I think it might be an issue with how the programs render the typical TeX fonts on non-retina displays. (This is a conjecture, I am not an expert on this.) For example, using a dual-screen setup (external monitor + laptop screen) I have the following effect. The text in the preview screen (in TexShop for instance) is noticeably blurry when I view it on my external monitor. (As described in the original post.) This did not happen before the installation of the new OS. When I move the same preview window onto the retina laptop

Comment: Is this a comment? On this site, answers are rather expected to be solutions. Thoughts are better suited as comments.

Comment: @Stefan: This is (1) too long for a comment (as comments are limited to 560 chars); (2) very helpful as it points to where the problem is likely to lie.

Comment: (1) The fact that it's too long for a single comment doesn't mean that it's OK to post it in the answer box.  It's still a comment.  (2) The fact that it gives some clues towards narrowing down what the problem might be doesn't make it an answer.  Still sounds to me like a comment....

Comment: Well, this should be converted to a comment then, if it's helpful

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I had the same problem after installing Yosemite. I had the latest version of TexShop installed (Version 3.43), but only the TeXLive-2012 Tex distribution. The problem of blurriness is completely gone for me after installing the latest TeXLive distribution, TeXLive 2014, which you can download from www.tug.org/mactex/ This is what I get now after running textdist from the terminal:
$ texdist --list
TeXLive-2012.texdist
TeXLive-2014.texdist
$ texdist --current
TeXLive-2014

Comment: Changing to tl2014 didn't solve it for me. :(

Comment: Richard Koch has released a version 3.44 of TeXshop. The release notes have some suggestions for how to make things defuzzified. None of these did anything for me...

Comment: So there is now a version 3.45 of TeXshop. Using that along with the command: "defaults write TeXShop FixPreviewBlur YES"  did the trick for me (MacBook Air 11", mid-2011)! I would post this as an answer, but it seems I lack the reputation to do so.

Comment: I had the same problem. The command (from the terminal) "defaults write TeXShop FixPreviewBlur YES" also worked for me.

Comment: So I found a web page with something that has solved the problem for me, and probably others. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602718.  The suggestion there is to "Reduce Transparency" in the Accessibility section of the System Preferences and Reboot. The FixPreviewBlur made it workable. This seems to completely remove the problem. (I cannot post this as an answer due to a lack of rep).

Comment: Just to clarify: this bug is not related to either TeXWorks or TeX fonts. It’s a bug in the PDF renderer in OS X Yosemite on non-Retina displays. There does not appear to be a real solution for the problem, and as of 01·2016 there’s no bug fix provided by Apple. Something that’s touted as a  workaround is to disable font smoothing but this obviously doesn’t actually fix the bug, and in fact makes font display worse (font smoothing is designed to *improve* text display, and should be enabled). Likewise, reducing transparency is unrelated to the display of PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off (uncheck) "Use LCD font smoothing when available" under 'System Preferences > General'. This worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me. It was among the first things I did. I'm also puzzled that it must depend not just on the OS but on the particular way TeXShop is processing, as things appear fine in Adobe Reader, Preview ... or, in fact, in TeXWorks!

Comment: Apparently this is an OS issue. See https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/2joxlh/os_x_yosemite_1010_bug_thread/cleisr8